# Change numbers only font family in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, styles, font-family

I have a complete application and I'm using a custom font.

Is there a way to use two font families one for Text and one for numbers only?

Bearing in mind that the texts and numbers from API and they are mixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it. I used `GoogleFonts` for getting different fonts but you can replace it with any style you want to get the font you need. As you can see you can even adjust colors and sizes like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(children: [
      MyText('test test 123 32123 tter213'),
      MyText('qqqqqq'),
      MyText('11111111'),
      MyText('123bla, 123 blablabla'),
    ]))));
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  MyText(this.text, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?=\d)(?<=\D)');
  final RegExp number = RegExp(r'\d');

  late final List<String> split = text.split(regExp);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
          children: split
              .map((e) => number.hasMatch(e)
                  ? TextSpan(
                      text: e,
                      style: GoogleFonts.vampiroOne(
                          color: Colors.red, fontSize: 30),
                    )
                  : TextSpan(
                      text: e,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
                    ))
              .toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can use two different font families in flutter but I don't think flutter will apply them separately one for number and one for text, you manually will have to change the font family.