# Flutter : How to include multiple font family in one paragraph?

Tags: flutter, dynamic, fonts, locale

There are 2 types of language in one paragraph, see example below.
And it comes from rest API. I want to use different font families for each language.

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. জীবের মধ্যে সবচেয়ে সম্পূর্ণতা মানুষের। কিন্তু সবচেয়ে অসম্পূর্ণ হয়ে সে জন্মগ্রহণ করে। বাঘ ভালুক তার জীবনযাত্রার পনেরো- আনা মূলধন নিয়ে আসে প্রকৃতির মালখানা থেকে। Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.  জীবরঙ্গভূমিতে মানুষ এসে দেখা দেয় দুই শূন্য হাতে মুঠো বেঁধে। It has survived five centuries and the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

Here is flutter `TextStyle`

```
Text('Sample Text, who come from api',
style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Roboto"),)
```

How can I make this font `fontFamily` dynamic?

Comment: Is there a semantic change? In such case use `<span>` (e.g. if you cite the other language). Else do not do it (but provide fall-back families), so that the font engine will select similar fonts in all languages)

Comment: Maybe you could do something similar like what is used in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346786/change-numbers-only-font-family-in-flutter

Comment: @Ivo I believe it will work split with space
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74347509/12902996

Comment: I edited because (for reasons not your fault - just unlucky) I had the impression that your post would attract unwanted kind of reactions. Feel free to point out if I accidentally broke your meaning. Please accept my apology in that case.

Comment: See you just need to check the text with `RegExp` as it's english or bengali at the receiving response and pass a check if it's english and show `TextStyle` accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by my previous answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74347509/12902996 I edited it for your use case:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                  child: MyText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. জীবের মধ্যে সবচেয়ে সম্পূর্ণতা মানুষের। কিন্তু সবচেয়ে অসম্পূর্ণ হয়ে সে জন্মগ্রহণ করে। বাঘ ভালুক তার জীবনযাত্রার পনেরো- আনা মূলধন নিয়ে আসে প্রকৃতির মালখানা থেকে। Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. জীবরঙ্গভূমিতে মানুষ এসে দেখা দেয় দুই শূন্য হাতে মুঠো বেঁধে। It has survived five centuries and the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."),
                ))));
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  MyText(this.text, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'(?<=\s)');
  final RegExp alphanumeric = RegExp(r'\w');

  late final List<String> split = text.split(regExp);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
          children: split
              .map((e) => alphanumeric.hasMatch(e)
              ? TextSpan(
            text: e,
            style: GoogleFonts.vampiroOne(
                color: Colors.red, fontSize: 30),
          )
              : TextSpan(
            text: e,
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
          ))
              .toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

I made the split between alphanumeric and not. I'm not sure if it's 100% what you want but you can give it a try.