# Flutter style Text

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I'm solving the text style. I have String like this :
"@123 #123 text normal `<ins>`
@tag #hashtag text normal  `</ins>`

- Inside  insert  tag(`<ins>` and `</ins>`) text normal  will be red.
  Hashtag vs tag will be red but bold.
- Outside the insert tag(`<ins>` and `</ins>`): normal text will be black. hashtag vs tag will be black but bold .
- Does anyone have a solution or package that can solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: This question might help you in the right direction. The same principal can be applied for you I think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346786/change-numbers-only-font-family-in-flutter

Comment: tks for comment .I just update question .can you help me this ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I used two things: Regex to recognize each tag and hashtag, and RichText widget for different styles, and it can definitely be improved, but I think it can give you an idea to solve this problem.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MyText(
                  "@12345 #12345 text normal @tag123 #hashtag123 text normal for test and it can be more and more @tag123 #hashtag123 text normal for test and it can be more and more @tag123 #hashtag123 text normal for test and it can be more and more"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  MyText(this.text, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final RegExp tagRegex = RegExp(r'@(\w+)');
  final RegExp hashtagRegex = RegExp(r'#(\w+)');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<InlineSpan> formattedText = [];

    final List<String> words = text.split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (tagRegex.hasMatch(words[i])) {
        formattedText.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: words[i],
            style: TextStyle(color:Colors.red),
          ),
        );
      } else if (hashtagRegex.hasMatch(words[i])) {
        formattedText.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: words[i],
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        formattedText.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: words[i],
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
          ),
        );
      }
      if (i < words.length - 1) {
        formattedText.add(TextSpan(text: ' '));
      }
    }

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: formattedText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I should mention that I updated my answer based [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346786/change-numbers-only-font-family-in-flutter).
I hope it helps.

Comment: I mean this string above ins example .I may case all tag and all hashtag have a lot of in String ? not particular like '@123" or  "#123" .I mean it's is  regular expression  tag and hashtag

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I will change the answer now.

Comment: tks  Mohammad Fallah but my question is dificiency .I just update it .my question have tag <ins> and </ins> inside